# JS Translate onclick

Tags: javascript, css

When I first click the button it shows the hidden container but with no transition. On each consecutive click the transitions works fine.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hidden-div-1");
  if (x.style.transform === "translateY(0)") {
    x.style.transform = "translateY(100%)";
  } else {
    x.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
  }
}
//moves the 2nd div out of the way
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("hidden-div-1").style.transition = "all .5s";
  document.getElementById("hidden-div-1").style.transform = "translateY(100%)";
}
```

CSS For that element is:

```
transform: translateY(100%);
    
>! background-color: saddlebrown;
>! grid-column: col-st 1 / col-nd 6;
>! grid-row: 1 / 16;
>! z-index: 4;
```

I've spent some time on the code, but I'm not very well versed with JS and I got stuck

Comment: On the first run through, the `x.style.transform` *probably* does *not* equal `"translateY(0)"` (it's probably null/undefined/"" etc).   Switch your `if` around and look for the known value`"translateY(100%)"`.  Or debug and see what it *does* equal.

Comment: `document.getElementById("hidden-div-1").style.transition = "all .5s"` this should be added by default. Just add `transition: all .5s` to your css file